# PHP undefined variable error when getting the MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing something like a "e-diary" (for schools, education project) in PHP. I have a problem with database records.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\edziennik\panel.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined variable: surname in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\edziennik\panel.php on line 44
```

My code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) or !empty($_POST['surname'])){
    require('inc/database.php');
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `studentindex`");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Imię</th>
                  <th>Nazwisko</th>
                  <th>Klasa</th>
                </tr>
            </thead><tbody>';
            $row = array();
    foreach ($result as $row){
      if ($row['name'] == $name or $row['surname'] == $surname){
        echo '    <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['surname'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['class'].'</td>
                  </tr>';
      }
```

Exact problem is in foreach, where the if giving that error, in other PHP versions everything was OK (with MySQL). I'm using PDO actually, in database.php is only connection that works fine.

### Edit

I have error `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\edziennik\panel.php on line 48` now.

These lines:

```
echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$row['id'].'</td> // line 48
    <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['surname'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['class'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: $row['name'] == $name or $row['surname'] == $surname //have you assigned value for the variables $name, $surname?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if (!empty($_POST['name']) or !empty($_POST['surname'])){

You have to add variables and assign values:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
```

Comment: Or, more lightweight, less confusing: replace the single occurrences of `$name` and `$surname` directly by `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['surname']`...

Comment: I have `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\edziennik\panel.php on line 48` error now.

Comment: @fox what fields are in table "studentindex"? The same you have to set in $row['...']

Comment: @c4pricorn in this table is person's ids (id, name, surname, class)

Comment: SELECT * FROM `studentindex` - delete ` chars

Comment: @c4pricorn the problem was this in mysql it says ID... I'm very beginner in php.